# How to debug handle in transaction email templates?

Tags: email, email-templates, shipment, debugging, transactional-mail

How can I debug a transaction email template?
In the admin panel I select in configurations -> sales the email template for shipment. It has the template-id 75. So far everything is totally normal.

Next I call sendMail with that templateId 75 and Magento sends that email template but the handler I defined there seems not to be called.
When I debug the defined template files in my handle the debugger ignore my breakpoints in that file. So it seems that this handle was not called.
How can I debug this? Or how can I check if in my sales.xml this handler will be called?

**UPDATE:**
It seems that I cann call the standard handle 'sales_email_order_items' but not my new handle in the same 'sales.xml'.
First guess it could be the wrong store but after debugging the storeId (1) is correct.

**UPDATE 2: SOLUTION**
Never copy paste code, always try to write just a little "Test output" to see, if that Template is called.
My mistake because I had some conditions that should never pass.